# Javascript not always loaded, but it's included in head

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have Ruby on Rails project, where I use a third party library ([editablegrid](https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid)). I placed the files in `vendor/assets/javascripts` and I have included the library in the layout file that for views that need it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mcf</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'dynamic_collections' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "editablegrid" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "editablegrid_editors" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "editablegrid_renderers" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "editablegrid_utils" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "editablegrid_validators" %>
</head>
  <body>


<%= yield %>

</body>
```

The generated html always has the `<script>` tags for editablegrid, but the browser does not always load it. The js files can always be loaded from the urls generated by `javascript_include_tag`.

The pattern I noticed in whether js loads or not is that, js won't load if I click a link leading to the page except if js already loaded once on the same tab. Typing the page's url in the addressbar or refeshing the page will load js. I tested this pattern on Chromium.

In Chromium's Elements devtool only editablegrid javascripts don't show up, all other js files seem to be loaded.

Versions:

```
Ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636)
Rails 4.2.5
Chromium 47.0.2526.106 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)
Firefox 43.0.4 (Bug is there, didn't test for pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

The js should always be put at the end of an HTML file. Since you are using rails and jquery you can tell your js code to wait for the page to be loaded with a :

> ```
> $(document).on('page:load', ready)
> ```

and encapsulate your js code in a 'ready' function

> ```
> ready = -> ### place your code here
> ```

Sorry this is coffee formated js code...

EDIT : 
When browsing the examples at : [GitHub Editablegrid page](https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid/)

You can notice that the function you will place in "ready -> " will depend on the type of input data you have.

here is an example to plug editable grid to a HTML table (it's not my example but the one from the demo) :

```
 editableGrid = new EditableGrid("DemoGridAttach", { sortIconUp: "up.png", sortIconDown: "down.png"}); 

            // we build and load the metadata in Javascript
            editableGrid.load({ metadata: [
                { name: "name", datatype: "string", editable: true },
                { name: "firstname", datatype: "string", editable: true },
                { name: "age", datatype: "integer", editable: true },
                { name: "height", datatype: "double(m,2)", editable: true },
                { name: "country", datatype: "string", editable: true, values: 
                    { 'Europe': { "be" : "Belgium", "fr" : "France", "uk" : "Great-Britain", "nl": "Nederland"},
                      'America': { "br" : "Brazil", "ca": "Canada", "us" : "USA" },
                      'Africa': { "ng" : "Nigeria", "za": "South-Africa", "zw" : "Zimbabwe" }
                    }
                },
                { name: "email", datatype: "email", editable: true },
                { name: "freelance", datatype: "boolean", editable: true },
                { name: "lastvisit", datatype: "date", editable: true }
            ]});

            // then we attach to the HTML table and render it
            editableGrid.attachToHTMLTable('htmlgrid');
            editableGrid.renderGrid();
        }
```

`
This is the kind of function you will place in the ready function

Comment: What code should I place in that function? I already call my data loading function from a script tag at the end of `<body>`. The error is that it doesn't see the classes that should be defined in the js file included in`<head>`

Comment: When you browse the examples at : [link]https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid you see that depending on your input data format you should add different functions in your HTML page. For instance if you want to create an editable grid on an HTML table you should add the code : `editableGrid = new EditableGrid("DemoGridAttach", { sortIconUp: "up.png", sortIconDown: "down.png"}); 

    // we build and load the metadata in Javascript
   } `

Comment: This line is in a function called at the end of `<body>`, that should be equivalent to calling it in a `load` event handler. Most of the time it works perfectly, but sometimes it says, that EditableGrid is undefined.

Comment: I kind of had the same problem with a wysiwyg editor. I added the js directly in my view but it only worked when I uploaded the page or accessed it by it's url in the address bar. When working with rails, it's a better practice, in my humble opinion, to add the js in the asset directory.